# How to send external events to FreeSwitch ESL

Tags: freeswitch, ivr

I have a requirement where User needs to listen to hold music, until a operator approves his call, then ESL can bridge the call, otherwise hangup. Question is how do I tell ESL that operator has approved the call. After reading bit more, what I need is
`loop_play(file); //Until I receive a interrupt for this connection` 
But I am thinking this is not possible as ESL has to readEvent(poll for events) and cannot be pushed to it. Is this correct? If yes, my next question is - can a external application (not Freeswitch) connect to ESL to send a event for a particular connection? I can make ESL do other types of polling like poll for a db record to be updated, but is there a event based mechanism that I am not aware of.

Tried db update method